# Best practice for deploying EAR-project to remote WildFly server via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, wildfly

I have a JavaEE EAR-project that I want to seamlessly deploy from Eclipse to a remote server running Debian and WildFly. I am today deploying using FTP to drop the .ear-project in the WildFly deployment folder (and then of course creating the .dodeploy) but this is not a very agile solution since I want to be able to push changes immediately.

Is there anyone with a recommendation of what is the best practice for such a solution? I've searched the web but couldn't find any concrete guides although using Maven in some way seems to be popular. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any best practice. In general it depends on your environment.

Following approaches are possible for deployment on remote host.

1. Using Maven

   - Detailed documentation about the plugin is available here https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/
   - Sample applications using the plugin are available here https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart
2. Using CLI

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes

```
sh $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --controller=<management_port_bind_address_remote_host>:9990 --connect --user=<management_user> --password=<management_user_pswd> --command="deploy <path_to_ear_file>"
```